# Transforming name of date

Tags: angular, typescript

I have application (table application) in Angular 2 with typescript. And i get some data from server with GET (http service):

```
private baseURL: string = "http://101.16.7.32/backend";
public getListsServices(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + this.listsUrl);
}
```

And in one of column i get a date in this format `2016-11-01T09:23:56.870189+03:00` (this date i get from server).

Now, my task is show only date - `2016-11-01`, and time dont using and showing. 
What i should do? Create some custom `@Pipe`? 
Like this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'transformingDate' })
export class TransDate implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): string {
    return (!!value) ? 'date' : 'false';
  }
}
```

Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html):

```
<div>{{myDate | date: yMd}}</div>
```

Will output `2016/11/01` if `myDate` is `2016-11-01T09:23:56.870189+03:00` (that's an ISO string).

*Check the documentation link if you want to customise of the output.*